# Alignment of the pipeline in ADF gets re-arranged automatically

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Every time I refresh/reopen the Azure Data Factory page, the alignment of the pipeline I have created gets rearranged automatically into a straight line. Is there a way to save the alignment of the pipeline?

Comment: pipelines automatically rearranged into a straight line? I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to say. In ADF, pipelines list is present on left side. The order of the pipeline doesn't matter. where you are aligning your pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

There is not. Azure Datafactory pipelines are stored as jsons. There is no indication of your arrangement, only the relations and entities created.

So each timea pipeline is loaded, ADF draws it as optimal as it thinks with the relations and entities existing.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to disturb the alignment when you debug, you can Right click on the empty space in your pipeline and click Lock Canvas. This will make sure to not disturb the way you arranged the activities. But the moment you close and reopen all the alignment would be gone and activities are arranged one after the other. Right now there is no way to stop this behavior.